# After removing GWT inherited module from gwt.xml GWT still tries to load it

Tags: java, gwt

I've removed:

```
inherits name='com.google.gwt.widgetideas.WidgetIdeas'
inherits name='com.google.gwt.libideas.LibIdeas'
```

And the corresponding jars (GWT Incubator) from my project and gwt.xml but I'm still facing this issue when I compile :

```
Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.WidgetIdeas'
[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/widgetideas/WidgetIdeas.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Any clues ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Clean he project in eclipse
2. Rebuild the project

If the above don't help:
check if any other projects which your main project depend on them still inherut your libraries in their `gwt.xml` files.